# STM32F407 CubeIDE

Tags: c, arm, stm32, cortex-m

systick is not working.

I have tried to simply enable the systick from its memory register:

```c
    uint32_t *pSCSR = (uint32_t*)0xE000E010;

    //do some settings
    *pSCSR |= ( 1 << 2);  //Indicates the clock source, processor clock source
    *pSCSR |= ( 1 << 1); //Enables SysTick exception request:
    
    //enable the systick
    *pSCSR |= ( 1 << 0); //enables the counter
```

I have tried the above code but it is not calling the systick handler as given below:

```c
void SysTick_Handler(void){
    printf("--------------systick handler----------\n");
}
```

Comment: Have you actually enabled the interrupt in the NVIC? Your `pSCSR` variable should really be volatile. And calling `printf()` in an ISR is almost certainly a terrible idea. Most embedded systems don't even have a functioning `printf()` function, unless you've gone to some effort to make that work.

Comment: SysTick is not in NVIC, it's an exception, not an interrupt, it doesn't need anything done in NVIC (its interrupt is configured in SCB or similar peripheral, where hardfault priority can be set, but systick exception is on by default). Try simply reading systick counter value when it's supposed to run. Does it change or is it stuck at zero? Also, please post the entire SysTick configuration, with reload value and counter value initialization. And yes, make all register pointers pointers to volatile, it's a necessity, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: I have tried to run by inserting the break points and it was not going into the systick handler function. I was just currently enabling all three bits of systick handler and seeing weather it is working or not